# How many 2N2222 transistors required for 3x3 LED matrix to mutiplex

Tags: arduino, transistors, led, bjt, led-matrix

[image]

I have made a 3x3 LED matrix and was able to turn them on/off individually using an Arduino, but now I want to use an external 3 V instead of the Arduino pin voltage.

How many 2N2222 transistors are required and how the connections should go?

Comment: Your schematic is soooo wrong.

Comment: Please let me know what mistake it has. I was able to turn on/off individual LEDs and so now I am planning  going ahead with external power source using 2n2222 transistor.

Comment: that is not a 3x3 matrix ... only the bottom 3 LEDs are in an arrangement that will allow each LED to be lit separately

Comment: I followed this tutorial  https://youtu.be/ZAUsyGyoyWs and i was able to light individual leds buy connecting +ve to col and gnd to rows

Comment: As to what’s wrong with your schematic, you’ve drawn the top 3 LEDs all shorted to each other, same with the next 3. What you meant to draw (and how you must have wired it if it worked) was that the anodes of the 3 LEDs in each column are connected together, and the cathodes of each row are connected together. (The cathode is the side of the LED with the flat line, the anode is the triangle side.)

Answer (score 1):

As above, the schematic is not correct for your question.

For the question:  6.  Three emitter followers for the columns, and three saturated switches for the rows.

If you invert the signals for the columns, those three transistors become PNP saturated switches, such as a 2N2907, 4403, 3906, etc. for a little more voltage available to each LED.

Comment: Thanks. Please tell what is the mistake. I am trying to make character display and it seems to work well with arduino digital pins. And so, now i am adding 2n2222 to source externally.

Comment: The schematic in Michael's answer shows the correct connections.

Answer (score 1):

The diodes are Leds.
If you want to make a time multiplex like one row at the time, only 3 series Led resistors are needed (R1,R2,R3).
For all Leds on simultaniously every Led must have own series 220 ohm resistor.

All resistors are calculated for 2mA per Led. If you want to use it for higher current Leds you must lower R7,R8,R9 base resistors like 1k even less (220 ohms series resisitors also).

And remember, using NPN as high side decreses the supply voltage -0.7v at least (so from 3v3 you get 2v6 only to supply Led+series resisitor).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for detailed reply. As per the above schematic ,do we need transistors for each row and columns? I guess the Transistors on P1,p2,p3 are for controlling external voltage. But whats for pins 4,5,6?

Comment: Pin1 "On" supplies the anodes in all first row. With Pin 4..6 you will choose which one of these three diodes is glowing. Then turn off Pin1 a turn on Pin2 (second row) and select which Led you want to be on in second row.

Comment: IIs it possible to use Arduino digital pins as GND instead of Q 4,5,6 ?

Comment: Yes, but all led current will flow thru arduino pin, inside arduino, arduino gnd pin and back to minus power supply. If you are going tu use a small leds its ok, if more than 10mA dont go this way. With three leds in one time its a lot.

Comment: I forgott to mention, you can use PNPs as Q1..3 if arduino voltage (voltage on pins) is the same as Vcc for Leds (Base resistor =10k will be enough). Then voltage available for Leds will be all Vcc. But in case Vf of diode is 2V the rest 1V (Vcc=3V) will be waisted one way or another (transistor Vce or series Led resistor).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Michal.